# What's the correct regex for a required string and optional string in Django?

Tags: regex, django, url-pattern

So in my Django URLS I want to be able to support:

mysite.com/section

mysite.com/section/

mysite.com/section/sectionAlphaNum

mysite.com/section/sectionAlphaNum/

I currently have as the URL pattern:

```
(r'^section/(?P<id>\s?)?', section)
```

Which should make **section/** required and anything after optional, but it never seems to catch whatever sectionAlphaNum I enter in. In my **views.py** file I have

```
def section(request,id):
    if id == '':
        # Do something with id
    else:
        # Do default action
```

But it never seems to get into the top if branch where it does something with the id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(r'^section(?:/(?P<id>\w+))?/$', section)
```

Notice the last `?` to make the whole `(?:/(?P<id>\w+))` optional.

*Other answers are missing the `?` or they don't make one of the slashes (`/`) optional like I do with the first one in `(?:/(` ...*

```
r'^section/(?:(?P<id>\w+)/)?$'  # same result, last '/' optional.
```

And make the parameter optional in the function as well:

```
def section(request, id=None):
    # ...
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked (the second code snippet you provided). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following syntax: `(r'^section/(?P<id>\w+)/$', section)`?

Comment: @JaredJoke Correct, I typed too fast!  :)

Answer (score 1):

In regular expressions the `^` and `$` represent the start and end of the string respectively.

Hence the URL to display `/section/` would be:

```
(r'^section/$', section_view)
```

while the URL to display a specific section `/section/section-id/` would be :

```
(r'^section/(?P<section_id>\w+)$', section_detail_view)
```

Ideally you have separate views in your `views.py`:

```
def section_view(request):
    # show page about the various sections

def section_detail_view(request, section_id):
    # show page about specific section by section_id
```

Answer (score 1):

urls.py:

```
...
(r'^section/$', section),
(r'^section/(?P<id>\w+)/$', section),
...
```

views.py:

```
def section(request, id=None):
    if id is None:
       ...
    else:
       ...
```

To append just slash (from `/section` to `/section/`) enable CommonMiddleware in Your settings' `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

Comment: I tried this and it seems to allow the optional idea but doesn't work when I do site.com/section

Comment: To append slash enable CommonMiddleware in Your settings, as I've described above.

Comment: Yeah, I have that. It already appends the slash. I'm saying if I omit the optional part "sectionAlphaNum" it doesn't match the url